# Storage account doesn't exist, cannot find reference for Function App

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-functions

I wrote two functions in Azure. One function used a storage account and the other used SQL storage. 
Both were under the same App Service.

Happy with my approach with the SQL function I wrote, I deleted the function I didn't need, then the storage account.

Following this the App Service complained it could no longer contact the storage account (not used by the remaining function).

```
"Storage account xxx doesn't exist. Deleting the storage account the function app is using will cause the function app to stop working. Update the app setting with a valid existing storage connection string."
```

Then

```
"We are not able to retrieve your functions right now. Please try again later"
```

I removed the line referencing the storage from the function app settings, but this has made no difference. Restarting also makes no difference.

The stupid thing is I cannot access the code from the Functions app in Azure, I wrote it all online.

Is there any recovery from this?

I'm guessing there is a reference to the removed storage somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: Azure Storage is used by Azure Functions engine itself - for logging, dashboard etc.

Comment: @Mikhail Darn. is my function code recoverable, or is that gone too?

Comment: That I don't know... But it's a good idea to setup deployment from VS or source control next time ;)

Comment: I'm about to rewrite it, from VS this time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Azure Storage is required by the Function App. Unfortunately, your function code is not recoverable, as Azure Functions uses an Azure Storage Files share on that storage account as the underlying filesystem.

Normally you could access the code from Kudu endpoint. Go to Platform Features for the function app --> Advanced Tools (Kudu)
--> Debug Console -->site --> wwwroot